# How to test a (possible) unknown type?

Tags: powershell, types, powershell-core

[**PowerShell Core**](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) appears to have [semantic versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-core-60?view=powershell-6#semantic-versioning) which includes a new type accelerator called `[semver]` and is based on the [`System.Management.Automation.SemanticVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.semanticversion?view=pscore-6.2.0) class .

To test for this specific type in the PowerShell Core environment, you would probably use the syntax:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion -is [semver]
```

But if you implement this in a script and run this in the [**Windows PowerShell**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/powershell) environment, you will get an error:

> ```
> Unable to find type [semver].
> At line:1 char:31
> + $PSVersionTable.PSVersion -is [semver]
> +                               ~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (semver:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
> ```

A similar error appears when I compare it to a type name (`string`):

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion -is `semver`
```

> ```
> Cannot convert the "semver" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
> At line:1 char:1
> + $PSVersionTable.PSVersion -is 'semver'
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
> ```

<sub>(It would have been nice/correct if PowerShell differentiates between providing a `[Type]` or a `'String'` as comparison and just return `$False` if the string cannot be converted)</sub>

What is the best way to test for a type and prevent any error if the type is unknown (as happens with the [`-is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators?view=powershell-6) operator for certain types in a specific environment)?

Comment: what happens if you wrap the type test in a `try/catch` block?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, yes that does indeed work but would often result very ugly extra statements like: `Try{$IsType = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion -is [semver]} Catch{$IsType = $Null};  If ($IsType) {...` and I generally try to avoid `Try/Catch` blocks as much as possible

Comment: i agree that it results in some ugly code ... but that can be wrapped in a function. both the method in your answer and the `try/catch` seem effective, so go with what suits your style. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [**vexx32**](https://github.com/vexx32) for this answer:
<sub>(see also: [Feature Request: -Is operator: suppress "Cannot convert"error #10504](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10504))</sub>

```
'UnknownType' -as [type] -and $object -is [UnknownType]
```

E.g.:

```
'semver' -as [type] -and $PSVersionTable.PSVersion -is [semver]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer so far were I can come up with myself is:

```
$Object.PSTypeNames -Contains '.NET Framework type'
```

e.g.:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.PSTypeNames -Contains 'System.Management.Automation.SemanticVersion'
```

But that will make the use of a [type accelerators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-powershell-type-accelerators/) impossible.