# Powershell GetType

Tags: .net, powershell

I want to check is some type exist. For example:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition '
public class Test{
    public static int aaa(){
        return 1;
    }
}'

[test]::aaa() # 1

[type]::GetType('test') # empty
```

but GetType() not works for my 'test' type.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[test].GetType()` ?

Comment: I want to check type exist without error message. And still what's wrong with [type]::GetType() method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell Add-Type : Cannot add type. already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730978/powershell-add-type-cannot-add-type-already-exist) | [How do I conditionally add a class with Add-Type -TypeDefinition if it isn't added already?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16552801/7571258)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test a (possible) unknown type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805460/how-to-test-a-possible-unknown-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test if the type already exists with

```
if (-not ('Test' -as [type])) {
# or 
# if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'Test').Type) {
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition '
    public class Test{
        public static int aaa(){
            return 1;
        }
    }'
}
```

I don't know why `[type]::GetType('test')` doesn't work though, but

```
("Test" -as [type])
```

does work and returns either $null or

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                               
True     False    Test                                     System.Object
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66199775/45375), which undoubtedly shows the best solution (`-as [Type]`), with **why `[Type]::GetType('Test')` failed**:

- **[`System.Type.GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Type.GetType)** **only finds types from assemblies that were *loaded from or saved to disk*** - that is, types either loaded from preexisting assembly files or types in *dynamically* created assemblies *also, optionally, persisted to disk*.
- By contrast, **when you define types dynamically in PowerShell, they are created in *dynamic, in-memory* assemblies that are *not* persisted to disk, so `[Type]::GetType()` doesn't see them**. Note that this applies equally to:

  - Types created with [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) `-TypeDefinition` or `-MemberDefinition`
  - Types created with the (PSv5+) `class` and `enum` keywords, i.e. custom PowerShell classes and enumerations.

---

However, `[Type]::GetType()` offers overloads that enable hooking **custom assembly-resolver functionality** into the type-lookup process, i.e. a way to look for types in assemblies in *additional* places.

This is presumably what **PowerShell uses behind the scenes to *include* its dynamic in-memory-only assemblies in the lookup process**, which comes into play in the following contexts (case-*insensitively*, as PowerShell generally is):

- In the most obvious form, in ***type literals*** (`[<typeName>]`), so that you can refer to your `Test` type as `[Test]`, for instance.

  - Such type literals therefore also work with `-is`, the [type(-inheritance) / interface test operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators), so you can test a given object for being of or deriving from the given type / implementing the given interface type.
  - Caveat: If the type name inside `[...]` isn't recognized as a loaded or dynamically declared type, an *exception* occurs, which surfaces as a *statement-terminating error* in PowerShell.
- In the context of **`-as`, the [conditional type conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators)**, as shown in Theo's answer (`'<typeName>' -as [type]`), where `[type]` refers again to [`System.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Type).

  - This approach tests if the string contains a type name that refers to a loaded type that can therefore be converted to a type-*information* object.
  - If so, such a type-information object is returned (the equivalent of `[Test]`, in your example); if not, `$null` is returned
  - In a Boolean context such as an `if` conditional, a type-information object getting returned is implicitly `$true`, where as `$null` is implicitly `$false` - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for the exact rules of implicit to-Boolean conversion), so the `-as [type]` approach is the most convenient way to test a type's presence.
- When you ***cast* a type-name string to `[type]`**: `[type] 'Test'`

  - Unlike the `-as` approach, this approach triggers an *exception* that surfaces as a *statement-terminating error* in PowerShell.
  - The (more verbose and less efficient) equivalent of `if ('Test' -as [type]) ...` is
    `if ($(try { [type] 'Test' } catch { $null })) ...`

---

A note re **namespaces**:

- **Types created with `class` and `enum` have *no* namespace component**, so it is sufficient to refer to the types by their own name alone, such as `[Test]` in the case at hand.
- **Types created via `Add-Type`**:

  - via **`-TypeDefinition`** (arbitrary C# code):

    - Whether you need a namespace qualifier depends on whether you enclose the new type's declaration in a `namespace <identifier> { ... }` construct or not.
  - via **`-MemberDefinition`** (C# code for declaring static methods, typically for [P/Invoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) calls):

    - You *do* need a namespace qualifier to refer to the resulting type, namely either the one you've specified explicitly via the `-Namespace` parameter or the the implicitly used `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddType.AutoGeneratedTypes.WinApi` namespace.
    - You can bypass having to refer to the type by namespace-qualified name by using the `-PassThru` switch and saving the type-definition object in a variable, which allows you to call its static methods directly via that variable.